# How to dynamically create an instance in java, from string with parameters?

Tags: java

I know this question is answered some time. But all the time the parameter is an object.
Thats what I want to replace:

```
if (s.equals("A")) { add (obj = new A(x,y)); }
if (s.equals("B")) { add (obj = new B(x,y)); }
if (s.equals("C")) { add (obj = new C(x,y)); }
```

I have this:

```
try
{
    Class cl = Class.forName(s);
    Constructor con = cl.getConstructor (x, y);
    obj = con.newInstance(x, y);
}
```

but it expect x,y as a class, but its an int. How to do this>

Comment: if you know that x,y are `int`s then maybe try `cl.getConstructor (int.class, int.class);`

Comment: autobox primitive values to wrapper classes `Constructor con = c1.getConstructor((Integer) x, (Integer) y);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
cl.getConstructor(int.class, int.class);
```

There are `Class` objects reflecting on primitive types, and even the `void` type has it reflective counterpart in `Void.class`.

Comment: may I ask more? It say "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A" but if I directly instantize that class A, it does work.

Comment: You must give the fully qualified class name to the reflective call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
cl.getConstructor(int.class,int.class);
```

to get the constructor with `(int,int)` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If x and y are `int`, try to call `getConstructor` by passing the type of the exptected parameters:

```
Class cl = Class.forName(s);
Constructor con = cl.getConstructor (Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
obj = con.newInstance(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to provide the types to the getConstructor method. That is

```
Constructor con = cl.getConstructor (x.getClass(), y.getClass());
```

or

```
 Constructor con = cl.getConstructor (ClassOfX.class, ClassOfY.class);
```